# Assigning id to rows according to categorical column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame of 15 subjects, with 3 columns :
`SONA_id` (random 5 digit number for each subject),
`action` (1/2),
`reward` (1/0).

Each subject have 401 rows (steps).
I want to assign each subject an id, a number in the range of 1:15.

Any way to do it in `dplyr` without using `case_when` and 15 cases?

Comment: You can do `match(df1$SONA_id, unique(df1$SONA_id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `d` is your dataset, you can do this:

```
d %>%
    group_by(SONA_id) %>%
    mutate(id = cur_group_id())
```

[`cur_group_id()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html#cur_group-and-cur_group_id) provides a unique numeric identifier for each group.

As an example:

```
> d
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  SONA_id
  <chr>  
1 AAAA   
2 AAAA   
3 BBBB   
4 BBBB   

> d %>% group_by(SONA_id) %>% mutate(id = cur_group_id())
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   SONA_id [2]
  SONA_id    id
  <chr>   <int>
1 AAAA        1
2 AAAA        1
3 BBBB        2
4 BBBB        2
```